# Acer Laptop Performance Loss Plugged in

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, performance, cpu, underclock

A few days ago I acquired a Brand New Acer Aspire E 15 E5-571-74AP laptop, and found a frustrating problem.

Whenever the laptop is unplugged, the performance on games and other programs is stunning.

Whenever it is plugged in however, the clock speed of the processor drops down below 1 ghz as low as 0.60 ghz and performance is severely reduced. The clock speed drops only when a demanding program is open, and the program uses the same amount of cpu no matter the clock speed. It is definitely not an overheating issue. When I plug in USB devices the clock speed goes down. Again all this happens only when the laptop is plugged in to charge. Performance change is instant.

Specs:

Intel Core i7-5500U 2.4ghz with Turbo Boost up to 3.0 GHz

Intel HD Graphics 5500 with up to 3839 MB Dynamic Video Memory

8GB 1600mhz DDR3 ram

1000 GB HDD

Windows 8.1

19V 2.1A AC/DC charger

I have tried changing the power options, making sure running on battery and while plugged in are exactly the same on high performance, I have tried removing event logs, I have tried removing all USB peripherals. It comes with bitdefender, an ebay app, amazon app, abMedia, Acer Recovery management, and Spotify. I tried disabling the start up programs and it did not help.

Comment: you were on to something with the power options, however the issue clearly isn't with the "Windows" power options. I'm confident the issue is with some Acer bloatware program, that came included with your computer, that's kicking in whenever you plug/unplug your computer. Check `services.msc`, `msconfig` (ie: Task Manager, start up tab), and `appwiz.cpl`. I once had an Asus laptop that would completely shut off when plugged in because of some proprietary program that would take control of power settings. The symptoms you describe are very reminiscent. I ended up having to completely remove it.

Comment: Any funny Acer apps on it? Anything you can do without? You know, one of those we-know-best apps? It may be something worth checking out.

Comment: It comes with bitdefender, an ebay app, amazon app, abMedia, Acer Recovery management, and Spotify. I tried disabling the start up programs and it did not help. Also i am not sure what i should be looking for in services or the msconfig.

Comment: Another thing to note, disabling Turbo boost by setting the maximum processor speed to 90% boosted the performance quit a bit, but it still suffers compared to running on the battery.